# Running wmic.exe using c# always produces the error message "The system cannot find the file specified." when it works in a command prompt

Tags: c#, wmic

Running wmic.exe using c# always produces the error message "The system cannot find the file specified." when it works in a command prompt.

C# assembly is built with "Any CPU" targeting .NET Framework 4.

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "wbem", "wmic.exe");
string arguments = @"/NAMESPACE:\\root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement10 PATH ServerNetworkProtocol";

Process process = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        FileName = fileName,
        Arguments = arguments,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true
    }
};

process.Start();

StreamReader output = process.StandardOutput;
StreamReader error = process.StandardError;

Console.WriteLine(output.ReadToEnd());
Console.WriteLine(error.ReadToEnd());

process.WaitForExit();
int exitCode = process.ExitCode;
process.Close();
Assert.AreEqual(0, exitCode);
```

Error Message:

```
Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<0>. Actual:<-2147024894>.
```

Standard Console Output:

```
Node - MyComputerName
ERROR:
Description = The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have also tried using:

```
string fileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%comspec%");
string arguments = string.Format(
    @"/C {0} /NAMESPACE:\\root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement10 PATH ServerNetworkProtocol",
    Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "wbem", "wmic.exe"));
```

but I experience the same issue.

When run on the command prompt, it produces the expected output and returns an exit code of zero:

```
c:\windows\system32\wbem\wmic.exe /NAMESPACE:\\root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement10 PATH ServerNetworkProtocol && echo %errorlevel%
Enabled  InstanceName  MultiIpConfigurationSupport  ProtocolDisplayName  ProtocolName
TRUE     SQLEXPRESS    FALSE                        Shared Memory        Sm
FALSE    SQLEXPRESS    FALSE                        Named Pipes          Np
FALSE    SQLEXPRESS    TRUE                         TCP/IP               Tcp
FALSE    SQLEXPRESS    FALSE                        VIA                  Via
0
```

I've also posted on the MSDN forums [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ebb2c363-0a3e-450b-82b2-d71a566a7941/running-wmicexe-using-c-always-produces-the-error-message-the-system-cannot-find-the-file).

Comment: What happens when you run the exe as admin?

Comment: In all cases, I am running the exe as admin.

Comment: So what is in the fileName variable ??

Comment: In the first example, c:\windows\system32\wbem\wmic.exe  
In the second example, c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe

Comment: Is it a 32bit/64bit thing with folder redirection.

Comment: I'm curious, why shell out to wmic when .NET can query WMI directly?

Comment: @ChristopherPainter I was testing with the command line locally because that same command line would eventually be run on another machine which may not have .NET already installed and also may not allow remote WMI for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the test process executing the code.

To resolve this issue I had to select: In Visual Studio > Test > Processor Architecture for AnyCPU Projects > x64.

Selecting "Auto" or "x86" results in the error that was mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

`@"C:\Windows\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe"` this path worked for me.

For more information refer:
[https://www.computerhope.com/wmic.htm#:~:text=Wmic%20is%20an%20external%20command,%5Cwbem%5CWMIC.exe](https://www.computerhope.com/wmic.htm#:%7E:text=Wmic%20is%20an%20external%20command,%5Cwbem%5CWMIC.exe).

Comment: That's the same path that `string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "wbem", "wmic.exe");` would create (if Windows is installed to `C:`), as noted in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23089575/running-wmic-exe-using-c-sharp-always-produces-the-error-message-the-system-can#comment35294063_23089575).

Comment: Thank you. I was able to resolve the issue as indicated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67526280/90287